# Why didn't Hank Pym carry Scott Lang in his 'tank' key chain?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-2015

In *Ant-Man*, when the good guys infiltrated PYM corps to destroy the Yellowjacket prototype. It would be much easier if Pym would have sneaked Scott Lang using his tank key chain rather the all the fuss.

Comment: Remember, they also needed to bomb the facility. For that, Ant-Man's backend access was mandatory.

Answer (score 10):

The keychain goes through security when Hank enters the building, we see the security officer handing it back to him after it has presumably been scanned. Hank knows this will be the case and the chances are biological matter would have shown up when Scott passed through.

[image: Hank's things including the keychain in a draw being handed to him by security]

It's also worth noting that Scott... and all the ants... enter through a way that means they have direct access to the backend of the facility to start sneaking around. So if they enter through the front door that means two things:

1. They will have to find another entry point for Scott to gain access to the backend.
2. The ants won't be able to come in to assist. The ants play a large part in the whole plan so not having them would really make the whole operation a lot harder.

Comment: “chances are biological matter would have shown up” — are they scanning for that? Wasn't it a regular metal detector or x-ray machine?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite not shown but Darren knew Scott was going to try and steal the Yellowjacket and had enhanced security so likely stepped it up to check for it. I’ll have a look later for anything confirming this, busy now.

Comment: Random observation: Hank Pym is on [blood thinners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticagrelor)...

Comment: I think the miscellaneous items are passed through a simple X-Ray machine which could become awkward when a human skeleton the size of an ant inside the tank shows up on the screen, granted that'd be very difficult to spot in the first place

Comment: @Gatchwar It's a *tank*, i.e. made of heavy metal armor.  There's no way X-rays would penetrate that.  (Not sure if the shrinking process would make the armor thinner with respect to X-rays - it's hard to say how fictional tech would affect stuff like that...)

Comment: it was a real tank, no way detector would have shown up any thing

Comment: Answer is based on guesswork. No evidence provided.

Comment: @JimmyVailer a lot of answers are based on guesswork with evidence to back up supporting points. You’ve got to guess whether they are complete guesswork pulled out of their A’s or something more. I’m pretty sure this isn’t the former even of this isn’t great but then there’s never going to be any canon information on this.